# An application of the Mean Value Theorem in lemma 2.1 of Gidas, Ni and Nirenberg

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with $C^2$ boundary and let $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ such that $\nu_1(x_0) > 0$, $\nu$ outer normal unit vector. For $\varepsilon > 0$ let $\Omega_\varepsilon = \Omega \cap B_\varepsilon(x_0)$, $u \in C^2(\overline{\Omega_\varepsilon})$, $u > 0$, $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega \cap B_\varepsilon(x_0)$. Then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $u_1 < 0$ in $\Omega \cap B_\delta(x_0)$

This is a lemma in the Famous Paper of Gidas, Ni and Nirenberg about symmetry results. The beginning of the proof is as follows:

Denote $S = \partial \Omega \cap B_\varepsilon(x_0)$. We can assume that $\nu_1 > 0$ on $S$, decreasing $\varepsilon$ if necessary. Since $u > 0$ in $\Omega$ and $u = 0$ on $S$, then $u_1 \leq 0$ on $S$. Indeed, if this was not the case, it would mean that $u$ arrives at $S$ ascending, that is, increasing towards $S$, which is absurd.

We proceed by contradiction.

If the lemma was false, there would be a sequence $(x_j)$ such that $x_j \to x_0$ and $u_1(x_j) \geq 0$. By continuity, $u_1(x_0) \geq 0$. On the other hand, we already know that $u_1 \leq 0$ on $S$, and thus
$$
u_1(x_0) = 0
$$
Moreover, if $j$ is sufficiently large, the interval in the $e_1$ direction going from $x_j$ to $\partial \Omega$ hits $S$ at a point $y_j$, where we know that $u_1(y_j) \leq 0$. It is clear that $u_1(y_j) \nearrow 0 \swarrow u_1(x_j)$, so $u_1(x_0) = 0$.

> By the Mean Value Theorem,
> $$
> u_{11}(x_0) = 0.
> $$

Why does this claim hold? How is the Mean Value Theorem used?

I'm really clueless.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

EDIT:

Precise reference:

B. Gidas. Wei Ming Ni. L. Nirenberg. "Symmetry and related properties via the maximum principle." Comm. Math. Phys. 68 (3) 209 - 243, 1979.

https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-68/issue-3/Symmetry-and-related-properties-via-the-maximum-principle/cmp/1103905359.full?tab=ArticleLink

Comment: Can you add a precise reference to this paper?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz done, with a lik to the paper

Comment: It would be good to note that you're referring to Lemma 2.1, and also to mention other assumptions (needed for the main claim).

Comment: I apologize if I'm missing something, but isn't this independent of the moving planes?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the equation satisfied by $u$ is not necessary to establish $u_{11}(x_0) = 0$ (see my corrected answer), but if you look up the proof, it shows up just after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer only addresses the claim $u_{11}(x_0)$, not the main claim.*

Let us say that we already know $u_1(x_0) = 0$. There are three possibilities:

- If $u_{11}(x_0) < 0$, then (by continuity) $u_{11} < 0$ on some neighborhood. In particular, for the one-variable function $g(t) = u(x_0 + t \mathbf{e_1})$ we have that $g''(t) < 0$. This means that $g'(t)$ is descreasing, but since $g'(0) = u_1(x_0) = 0$, we have $g'(t) > 0$ for $t<0$, which means that $g$ itself is increasing. But this is a contradiction with $u > 0$ inside $\Omega$ and $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$.
- If $u_{11}(x_0)$, then $u_{11} > 0$ on some neighborhood. For any $y \in \partial \Omega$ close to $x_0$ the function $g(y+t \mathbf{e_1})$ now has $g'' > 0$ (for small $t < 0$). Hence, $g'$ is increasing, but $g'(0) \le 0$, so $g' < 0$ for $t < 0$, and this is exactly the claim of the theorem.
- Finally, it is possible that $u_{11}(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense. But it is the Chain Rule, not the Mean Value Theorem, right?

Comment: Actually, why can't $g$ be strictly decreasing?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw a very stupid fundamental mistake. Can you un-accept the answer so that I can delete it?

Comment: I will think some more and then write again.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, my question only regards the claim that $u_{11}(x_0) = 0$, I can understand the rest of the proof (where, indeed, we use other assumptions). Now, if I get it correctly, the argument is as follows: In the case of $u_{11}(x_0) > 0$, the theorem is proved. If $u_{11}(x_0) < 0$, absurd. If $u_{11}(x_0) = 0$, we proceed as in the paper. Is that correct? Makes sense, but it is a bit odd that we are not using the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Yes, this is a very accurate outline of what I wrote. And you're right about it being a little odd; I suspect that the authors had some slightly different argument in mind (the one above doesn't involve $y_j$ at all).